# UPDATE: /login route throws an error which I cannot find the reason

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After hours of development it just decided to start rendering double and I cannot find the reason.
Please help!

[image: double rendering]

my app.js file

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Profile from "./components/Profile";
// import EditProfile from "./components/EditProfile";
// import CreatePost from "./components/CreatePost";
// import Login from "./components/Login";
import { AuthProvider } from "./AuthContext";
import PrivateRoute from "./components/PrivateRoute";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/user/:uid" component={Profile} />
          {/* <PrivateRoute
            exact
            path="/user/:uid/editProfile"
            component={EditProfile}
          />
          <Route exact path="/user/:uid/create" component={CreatePost} /> */}
          {/* <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} /> */}
        </Switch>
      </AuthProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

the component shown in the screen shot but all of them render twice

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../AuthContext";
import {
  Container,
  Row,
  Col,
  Card,
  Navbar,
  Button,
  Alert,
  Nav,
} from "react-bootstrap";
import Post from "./Post";
import "../style/profile.css";
import { database } from "../firebase";
import { faCheckCircle } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
// import Navigation from "./Navigation";

export default function Profile() {
  const { uid } = useParams();
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const { currentUser, logout, requestUserData } = useAuth();
  const history = useHistory();
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
  const [postData, setPostData] = useState([]);
  const [isUser, setIsUser] = useState(false);

  async function handleLogout() {
    setError("");

    try {
      await logout();
      // history.push("/login");
    } catch {
      setError("Failed to logout" + error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser && uid === currentUser.uid) {
      setIsUser(true);
    } else {
      setIsUser(false);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const usersRef = database.users;
    usersRef.where("userId", "==", uid).onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      setUserData(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })));
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const postsRef = database.posts;

    postsRef
      .where("creatorId", "==", uid)
      // .orderBy("createdAt")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        setPostData(
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }))
        );
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {/* <Navigation /> */}
      <Container>
        <Row className="ProfilePage">
          <Col>
            <Card style={{ width: "25rem" }} className="sticky-top">
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>
                  {userData.map((udata) => udata.name)}{" "}
                  {userData.map((udata) =>
                    udata.verification ? (
                      <FontAwesomeIcon
                        icon={faCheckCircle}
                        style={{ color: "#127FFF" }}
                        size="sm"
                      />
                    ) : (
                      ""
                    )
                  )}
                </Card.Title>

                {/* <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">
                  About me
                </Card.Subtitle>
                <Card.Text>About me content</Card.Text> */}
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            {postData &&
              postData.map((pdata) => (
                <Post
                  title={pdata.title}
                  nsfw={pdata.nsfw}
                  text={pdata.mainContent}
                />
              ))}
            {isUser ? (
              <Post
                title="It's a bit quiet in here. Don't you think?"
                button={
                  <Button variant="primary" disabled>
                    Make a new post  (not implemented yet)
                  </Button>
                }
              ></Post>
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

hope this details are enough

(stack overflow i don't have any more details to add for now please let me post this)

UPDATE from here:

the /login route throws an error pointing at the `ReactDOM.render` or it says that it prevents to render to prevent a render loop whichever it desides everytime

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of images. We can't help if we can't see what your code is doing.

Comment: What is rendering the `App` component? Are you rendering two of them somehow? Have you completely killed the development server, cleared cache & hard reload the browser, and restarted your local dev build?

Comment: it's impossible to render the component twice. And yes I have trayed to kill / clear cache / hard reload / restart but it doesn't seem to work and every time it throws a random error

Comment: It's not impossible at all to do `ReactDOM.render(<><App /><App /></>, rootEl);`, however silly that may be. Other than some trial and error by greatly reducing what `App` is rendering until it works again and incrementally adding back UI components one-at-a-time until it breaks and double renders, could you try creating a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this behavior that we can examine and live debug in?

Comment: So yeah I tried the `ReactDOM.render(...)` and it doesn't work.
The sandbox -> https://ij5dz.csb.app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are rendering a `children` prop twice in your `AuthContext`.

```
export function AuthProvider({ children }) {

  ...

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children} // <-- children
      {loading && (
        <CenteredContainer>
          <div className="align-middle text-center">
            <Spinner animation="grow" variant="dark" />
          </div>
        </CenteredContainer>
      )}
      {children} // <-- children
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

## Solution

Remove one of these rendered `children` props.

```
export function AuthProvider({ children }) {

  ...

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {loading && (
        <CenteredContainer>
          <div className="align-middle text-center">
            <Spinner animation="grow" variant="dark" />
          </div>
        </CenteredContainer>
      )}
      {children} // <-- render children only once
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit my-whole-react-app-renders-twice-and-driving-me-crazy]

Comment: oh god thanks but I still have a second problem which I thought was caused by this.
Please go on the /login route to see the whole nonsense

Comment: @AlexanderRoumeliotis What is the second problem? Feel free to edit/update your question.

Comment: @AlexanderRoumeliotis Ah, you've got some render looping. Taking a deeper look.

Comment: @AlexanderRoumeliotis In the [body](https://codesandbox.io/s/my-whole-react-app-renders-twice-and-driving-me-crazy-orjx0?file=/src/components/Login.js:983-1023) of `Login` component you've an unconditional `setLoading(false);` which updates state every time the component renders, which triggers the component to rerender. I think you've some routing issues as upon clicking the login link I see some logs I placed in `Login` but the URL doesn't update to "/login". And I see you are using anchor tags with hrefs instead of the react-router-dom `Link`s.

Comment: yeah but it worked before the `setLoading` is to handle some behavior in the button as you can probably see

Comment: @AlexanderRoumeliotis I fixed the `Nav.Link` issues in `Navigation.js` though I'm not really sure what additional behaviors you are referring to. Can you describe them in greater detail and include reproduction steps?

Comment: oh my god the `setLoading` was the problem indeed thanks a lot man.

Comment: last thing when I authenticate the user it doesn't fully authenticate until i re-sigin. can you please take a look?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230787/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-alexander-roumeliotis).